# cifs/samba client library

Tags: client, samba, smb, cifs

I'm looking for some stand alone library to access SMB/CIFS shares. 
I am not looking for mounting the shares, just browsing and accessing the files for reading.

Preferable something with a simple simple API similar to regular POSIX operations of `opendir`, `scandir`, `read` and etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you say nothing about the preferred language I would recommend looking on http://jcifs.samba.org especially http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html
it has what you ask for. Reading files, enumearating directories. API fairly simple.

Answer (score 2):

The libsmbclient shared library is part of samba provides simple API to access Windows file servers.

Answer (score 0):

[Pysmb](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb) is a good choice if you want to access samba shares from python.